# How can I copy the PDF of assets folder into a public directory and give the order to view it with Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, android, pdf

This is the code I am using, its pretty basic because its just two buttons (one for download Adobe acrobat and the other one to open the file with it) for simplify the access to a interactive PDF for my workers. The problem is that when I click on the button to open the PDF, Adobe Acrobat says that the file doesn't exist :(

I don't know how to program in Java actually, so if you can do it simple I will be very thankful :( Also Im spanish and my english can be a little bit bad :p

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    //Metodo boton descargar adobe acrobat
    public void descargar(View view) {
        Uri descargarac = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl");
        Intent DescargarAdobeAcrobat = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, descargarac);
        startActivity(DescargarAdobeAcrobat);
    }
    //Metodo boton descargar adobe acrobat
    public void visualizar(View view) {
        Uri path = Uri.parse("assets/ruta.pdf"); //This is the file
        Intent visualizarpdf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        visualizarpdf.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        startActivity(visualizarpdf);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you accomplished? Were you able to open the file with that code?

Comment: Use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream` on the asset content. Copy that to a file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Then use `FileProvider` to get the `Uri` to use with your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.9/PdfProvider) (and [its Kotlin equivalent](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.9/PdfProvider)) demonstrates the entire process.

Comment: @CommonsWare Its there a way we can chat and you can help me?

Comment: You are welcome to join [the Warescription](https://commonsware.com/warescription). In addition to getting a copy of [the book that covers the sample projects](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack), you would also have a access to chats and other developer support options. Alternatively, I made older editions of one of my books [available for free](https://commonsware.com/Android/4-2-free). The current latest of those is Version 7.3, which is 4 years old. However, it covers [a similar sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider).